# How can I change the source workspace in Matlab for 'linearize'?

Tags: matlab, function, simulink, workspace, linearization

is there a way to define the source workspace in Matlab for 'linearize' when used within a function?

Here a short minimal working example:

```
clear all
sys = 'watertank';
open(sys)
sys_io(1)   = linio('watertank/PID Controller',1,'input');
sys_io(2)   = linio('watertank/Water-Tank System',1,'openoutput');
linsys      = GetLinsys(sys,sys_io);
disp(linsys.a)
```

The function is:

```
function linsys = GetLinsys(sys,sys_io)
A       = 10;
linsys  = linearize(sys,sys_io);
end
```

The output is

```
-0.0500
```

since the `linearize` uses the inital value of A in the 'base' workspace (A=20) and not the value in the 'current' workspace (A=10).

However, I would expect

```
-0.1000
```

This is obtained if the code of the function is included in the script:

```
clear all
sys = 'watertank';
open(sys)
sys_io(1)   = linio('watertank/PID Controller',1,'input');
sys_io(2)   = linio('watertank/Water-Tank System',1,'openoutput');
A           = 10;
linsys      = linearize(sys,sys_io);
disp(linsys.a)
```

Thus, the question is: How can I get the same result using the function?

For the `sim` command, this can be done via the options:

```
options = simset('SrcWorkspace','current');
sim('modelname',[],options)
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698529/how-can-i-get-workspace-variables-in-matlab-function).
However, I couldn't find something similar in the linearization options.

Thanks a lot for any help or suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the standard way of passing parameters to Simulink is via the base workspace of MATLAB. To pass `A=10` to Simulink from a function, i.e. create a variable in the base workspace, you use the [`assignin`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html) function:

```
function linsys = GetLinsys(sys,sys_io)
    assignin('base','A',10);
    linsys  = linearize(sys,sys_io);
end
```

then, calling

```
sys = 'watertank';
open(sys)
sys_io(1)   = linio('watertank/PID Controller',1,'input');
sys_io(2)   = linio('watertank/Water-Tank System',1,'openoutput');
linsys      = GetLinsys(sys,sys_io);
disp(linsys.a)
```

yields

```
-0.1000
```

as expected.

Note, that this is a bit dangerous, as you overwrite any `A`, which is present in the base workspace at that time... As an alternative, I'd propose using the following function

```
function linsys = GetLinsys(sys,sys_io)

% Save old 'A', if exists
if evalin('base', 'exist(''A'',''var'')');
    baseA = evalin('base','A');
end
assignin('base','A',10)

% Function call
linsys  = linearize(sys,sys_io);

% Clean up
evalin('base', 'clear(''A'')');
if exist('baseA', 'var')
    assignin('base','A',baseA)
end

end
```

This checks if a variable called `A` exists in the base workspace and saves its value in `baseA`. Then you can safely assign the new `A` and call `linearize`. Finally, we `clear A` again and (if needed) re-assign the old `baseA`. - Not very elegant, but safer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But changing the variable in the base workspace is exactely what I would like to avoid by the function. Since it is possible for the sim command, I hope there is also a solution for the linearize command.

Comment: I included a work-around, which saves and restores any variable `A` which is present in the base workspace prior to the function call. Not an elegant solution, but does the job. Maybe (hopefully!) somebody comes up with a built-in, straightforward way to do this - I don't really like this solution either.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort! But again: The question is how to change to the 'current' workspace and not how to manipulate the base workspace :-) Hope someone has an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Within various of the files in MATLABROOT\toolbox\slcontrol\slcontrol that relate to linearization there is the following comment before the call to `sim`,

```
    % Run the simulation.  Do not need to simulate past
    % the final specified time.  Use the base workspace to write
    % variables and simulate.  This will be consistent with all
    % linearization functions that require the model parameters be
    % defined in the base workspace.
    S = simset('DstWorkspace','base');
    pmgr.sim([Tstart Tfinal],S);
```

I'd take from that that there is no easy/transparent (and possibly not even a difficult) way to get `linearize` to use the `Caller Workspace`.

Changing the above call to `sim` to use the `Caller` Workspace isn't an option because it would assume `Caller` is the function form where `sim` is being called, not from where you are calling `linearize`.

You might be able to set things up to get data from the `Model Workspace`, in which case you'd need to populate and set that workspace before calling `linearize`.